# Roll Multiple Dice and keep the best 3

Tags: javascript

I am working on a Dice Roller that will roll 3 or more dice.

What I need to do is make it so that no matter how many dice are rolled only the 3 best dice are kept.
Here is what I have so far:
(there is a dropdown box that has the player select the amount of dice rolled and thats what the `diceMethod.selectedIndex` is for)

```
function roll3d6() {
  d1=Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  d2=Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  d3=Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  return d1 + d2 + d3;
}

function roll4d6() {
  d1=Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  d2=Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  d3=Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  d4=Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  if ((d4<=d3)&(d4<=d2)&(d4<=d1)) { return d1 + d2 + d3; }
  else if ((d3<=d4)&(d3<=d2)&(d3<=d1)) { return d1 + d2 + d4; }
  else if ((d2<=d4)&(d2<=d3)&(d2<=d1)) { return d1 + d3 + d4; }
  else { return d2 + d3 + d4; }
}

function roll5d6() {
  d1=Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  d2=Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  d3=Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  d4=Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  d5=Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  if () {
    // Run check here
  }
}

function RollTheDice(){
  // roll 3d6
  if (document.form1.diceMethod.selectedIndex === 0) {
    score1=roll3d6();
  }
  // roll 4d6 best 3
  if (document.form1.diceMethod.selectedIndex === 1) {
    score1=roll4d6();
  }
  // roll 5d6 best 3
  if (document.form1.diceMethod.selectedIndex === 2) {
    score1=roll5d6();        
  }
}
```

My `roll4d6` works well but if possible I'd like to make it shorter, and I was hoping there was a simplified way to do the rolls so if I added more dice to the roll I wouldn't have to add to much more code to the dice check.

Comment: This question would be better posted on [codereview.se].

Comment: @TomFenech This question is borderline for Code Review, because asking for code to be written is off-topic there. One could argue that `roll4d6()` is to be reviewed, with the `roll5d6()` being an illustration of the direction that the author wants to go, but that would be a creative interpretation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following generic function:

```
function roll(n) {
    var a = Array(n);
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
    a = a.sort().slice(n - 3, n);
    return a[0] + a[1] + a[2];
}
```

where `n` is the number of dices we want to throw. With this function:

- We generate all random numbers for our dices.
- We sort them.
- We take the last three elements, which must be the biggest values.
- We return their sum.

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking to suggest...nice.

Comment: Works great, thanks. It cuts down on the amount of functions I have to make too.